# Fetch details of Azure service bus

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, azure, azureservicebus

I'm struggling to work out if there is a way to do what the project below is achieving

https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

I'm not sure if there is a way outside of a Dotnet app to fetch the details of all the topics and queues based on a service bus connection string.

I would like to create a simple React web app with potentially a Node or Dotnet backend if there is no easy way to get these details from Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceBus Explorer is using a .NET (Framework today, .NET Standard in the near future) SDK to implement the functionality. To be able to fetch metada about a namespace and all the entities' information you need an SDK for Service Bus. I am not aware of a React SDK. Currently supported SDKs are for .NET, Java, Python, Node.js, PHP, Ruby, and Go. You could have a look at the Node.js option [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/javascript/api/overview/azure/service-bus?view=azure-node-latest). There's also a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/service-bus-runtime-rest) you could use to discover entities.